# Upload document to cloudsearch use cs-import-documents

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I installed cs-import-documents after run the follow command line:

```
cs-import-documents -d http://mydomain.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com --source Documents/data.json`
```

I get the following error:

```
Content is not allowed in prolog. Unable to unmarshall error response ({
   "message": "Request forbidden by administrative rules", 
    "__type": "CloudSearchException" } ) 
(Service: AmazonCloudSearchv2; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: null)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have you AWS access keys set up correctly and it's rejecting you for lacking authorization.

This is covered in the "Installing Command Line Tools" section of the docs below -- have another look at that and double-check that you've followed all the steps correctly (particularly step 7 which deals with credentials)
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/using-cloudsearch-command-line-tools.html

Also for debugging (as mentioned in step 9 of the above link), try running `cs-import-documents` with no args. If you've set things up correctly, you should get the message "Expected at least one input source".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I configure CS_ENDPOINT incorrect.
But I get new error: 1 validation error detected: Value '[http://doc-test-domain-test_domain_id.ap-southeast-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/documents/batch]' at 'domainNames' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 28, Member must have length greater than or equal to 3, Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-z][a-z0-9\-]+] (Service: AmazonCloudSearchv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError)
Can you help me, please?

Comment: It sounds like there's something in your json data that doesn't meet the constraints. To simplify things, make sure you're testing with a single, minimal document. If that doesn't work, post the document and error as a new question, which will encourage others to take a look and help other people with that same question find the answer rather than it being buried in here.

Answer (score 0):

The error actually says it all Tran_Van_Moi. domainNames should be domainnames. The regular expression states `[a-z][a-z0-9\-]+]`. So no upper-case letters should fix this.